# GCC tries to assemble a .h file

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

It's an odd question which I don't really know how to ask.

I'm patching a kernel and when I try to build it, I get this

```
 devshark@ubuntu:~/KERNEL/linux_3.2.17$ make arch/arm/vfp
 CHK     include/linux/version.h
 CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
 make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
 CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
 AS      arch/arm/vfp/entry.o
 include/linux/thread_info.h: Assembler messages:
 include/linux/thread_info.h:12: Error: bad instruction `struct timespec'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:13: Error: bad instruction `struct compat_timespec'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:18: Error: bad instruction `struct restart_block{'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:19: Error: bad instruction `long (*fn)(struct restart_block*)'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:20: Error: bad instruction `union {'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:22: Error: bad instruction `struct {'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:23: Error: bad instruction `u32 __user*uaddr'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:24: Error: bad instruction `u32 val'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:25: Error: bad instruction `u32 flags'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:26: Error: bad instruction `u32 bitset'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:27: Error: bad instruction `u64 time'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:28: Error: bad instruction `u32 __user*uaddr2'
 include/linux/thread_info.h:29: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `}'
 ...
```

and it continues to list a few .h and .c files. I can build everything else just fine (so far) but building breaks at this point.

EDIT:

Ok, so I've done some research and here's the thing:

/arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h reports a

```
/home/devshark/KERNEL/linux_3.2.17/arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h:68:23: error: field 'restart_block' has incomplete type
```

the struct restart_block is defined in /include/linux/thread_info.h

and when I include it in the file, I get the aforementioned error.
here's how i'm including it

```
 #ifndef __ASM_ARM_THREAD_INFO_H
 #define __ASM_ARM_THREAD_INFO_H

 #ifdef __KERNEL__

 #include <linux/compiler.h>
 //#include <linux/thread_info.h>
 #include <asm/fpstate.h>

 #define THREAD_SIZE_ORDER  1
 #define THREAD_SIZE        8192
 #define THREAD_START_SP        (THREAD_SIZE - 8)

 #ifndef __ASSEMBLY__
 ...
```

but that turned out to be very bad. So what I did was to take a little step back, and found that in kernel/io.c i included asm/thread_info.h instead of linux/thread_info.h

So after some more hilarity ensued, I traced the root to a missing entry in the mach_types.

I'll be back with further info but this journey made me realize how much i hate (suck at) including files by myself :)

Comment: It seems that the assembly file is including a header file which does not check for inclusion in assembler files.

Comment: You mean #ifndef __THIS_HEADER__ ? I see that the assembly is pulling in a header but how do I prevent it or do anything about it? adding the -S option to gcc's CFLAGS didn't help either. How do I add that check?

Comment: My advice would be to _not_ include header files in assembly sources, unless you are 100% certain that they don't have any C constructs (like `struct` declarations). So start by remove _all_ header file inclusions, then add one by one until it builds or you get an error, then check if you really need that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was totally my bad, it seems that at some point I made two mistakes

1) was to include a wrong file that fixed the same problem the previous three files had
 2) to leave a commented-out include statement.

Number 1 was really obvious - the filename kept showing up repetedly but the hard part was finding where the error was. A little log sniping later and I spotted a line saying that 
"in file /arch/arm/kernel/io.c:" so I just went in there and swapped the asm/thread_info.h for linux/thread_info.h and that error went away.

The second real issue was also with asm/thread_info.h, but this time it was left commented out in some random file as i just fixed it and kinda forgot about it (three-way arm asm comparisons get heavy on the eyes) which manifested in vmlinux.vms being unable to be linked.

Giving errors like "unexpected symbol # at line 266" and such... going there I saw my problem and a quick grep with "//#include linux/thread_info.h" revealed the file that needed being fixed. All compilation problems were resolved and the uImage built nicely :))

But it didn't boot or at least tell me about it. So, case closed.